# How to set the default selected value of Dropdown on ASP.NET MVC View page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown that i need to set the default selected value from the database.

Example:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("state", " -- Select one -- ")%>
```

The above code binds records from the ViewData["specialty"] from my entity model.
And "Select One" is added on the top.
Now if i need my dropdown to set the default value to 'NY'. How can i do that?

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in a SelectList in the ViewModel

```
ViewData["States"] = new SelectList(states, "State_ID", "Name", "State_ID");
```

then

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("State_ID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["States"])%>
```

Comment: OK, but how does that set the default value?

Comment: The last parameter to the SelectList constructor in Wil's example would set the selected value to the item with a value of "State_ID".  If your list contained state names with abbreviations as their respective values, you would do the following: ViewData["States"] = new SelectList(states, "State_ID", "Name", "OH") to select Ohio.

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me. But the only thing is now i need to add "Select one" text to the selectList.